# Multiple views loaded into a template

Tags: django, templates, view

Hay guys, in PHP when i want to load a differnet page (render, with all variables outputting) i would use

```
include 'mypage.php'
```

This would load the page up and render the output.

How do i do something like this in Django? My problem is that i have a "quick list" which lists a bunch of popular items. I want this list to appear on every page, even if i don't call the object.

any ideas?

**EDIT: The view is called shop.app.popular_items**

Comment: I'm wondering if the right answer to this question is really template inheritance with an inclusion tag. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [template context_processors](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/)

Comment: Context processor only gives you the variables. You'll still need to handle the presentation somewhere, so you'll end up having the processor putting the values in the context automagically, but you'll have to put the right template code in all your templates, or include it. That's why I like Inclusion tags better ("Explicit is better than implicit").

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

After Daniel's answer and as you said you want to have it on every page,
**becomingGuru's answer** is probably the best solution.

---

This does not belong into the view (if you not want to display this as a standalone page).

This should go into a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question to becomingGuru on when to use context processors and when to use inclusion tags, remember that context processors are run on *every* template render. So they should only be used when you know you will always need the value.